# Nextflow capture output file by partial pattern

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I've got a Nextflow process that looks like:

```
process my_app {

    publishDir "${outdir}/my_app", mode: params.publish_dir_mode

    input:
        path input_bam
        path input_bai
        val output_bam
        val max_mem
        val threads
        val container_home
        val outdir

    output:
        tuple env(output_prefix), path("${output_bam}"), path("${output_bam}.bai"), emit: tuple_ch

    shell:
        '''
        my_script.sh \
            !{input_bam} \
            !{output_bam} \
            !{max_mem} \
            !{threads}

        output_prefix=$(echo !{output_bam} | sed "s#.bam##")
        '''
}
```

This process is only creating two `.bam .bai` files but `my_script.sh` is also creating other `.vcf` that are not being published in the output directory.

I tried it by doing in order to retrieve the files created by the script but without success:

```
output:
    tuple env(output_prefix), path("${output_bam}"), path("${output_bam}.bai"), path("${output_prefix}.*.vcf"), emit: mt_validation_simulation_tuple_ch
```

but in logs I can see:

```
Error executing process caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `null.*.vcf` expected by process `my_app_wf:my_app`
```

What I am missing? Could you help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the *output_prefix* has only been defined inside of the shell block. If all you need for your output prefix is the file's basename (without extension), you can just use a regular [script](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#script) block to [check file attributes](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#check-file-attributes). Note that variables defined in the script block (but outside the command string) are global (within the process scope) unless they're defined using the `def` keyword:

```
process my_app {

    ...

    output:
    tuple val(output_prefix), path("${output_bam}{,.bai}"), path("${output_prefix}.*.vcf")

    script:
    output_prefix = output_bam.baseName

    """
    my_script.sh \\
        "${input_bam}" \\
        "${output_bam}" \\
        "${max_mem}" \\
        "${threads}"
    """
}
```

If the process creates the BAM (and index) it might even be possible to refactor away the [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels) if an output prefix can be supplied up front. Usually this makes more sense, but I don't have enough details to say one way or the other. The following might suffice as an example; you may need/prefer to combine/change the output declaration(s) to suit, but hopefully you get the idea:

```
params.publish_dir = './results'
params.publish_mode = 'copy'

process my_app {

    publishDir "${params.publish_dir}/my_app", mode: params.publish_mode

    cpus 1
    memory 1.GB

    input:
    tuple val(prefix), path(indexed_bam)

    output:
    tuple val(prefix), path("${prefix}.bam{,.bai}"), emit: bam_files
    tuple val(prefix), path("${prefix}.*.vcf"), emit: vcf_files

    """
    my_script.sh \\
        "${indexed_bam.first()}" \\
        "${prefix}.bam" \\
        "${task.memory.toGiga()}G" \\
        "${task.cpus}"
    """
}
```

Note that the *indexed_bam* expects a tuple in the form: `tuple(bam, bai)`